# Deserialize a database table row straight into a C# object - is there a mechanism for this?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and this may end up being a dumb question but i need to ask anyway.

Is there a mechanism with C# to deserialize a result from an executed SQL statement into a c# object?

I have a C# program that reads a table from an sql server storing the row in an object - i am assigning each column value to an object member manually so i was wondering if there is a way to serialize the row automagically into an object. Or even better, a whole table in a collection of objects of the same type.

My environment is C#, VS2010, .NET4, SQLServer2008. 
The assumption is that i know the columns i need, it's not a select * query.

A link to a neat example will also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the columns named as per the table names, you can do this with LINQ-to-SQL without **any** mapping code - just using [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx):

```
using(var dc = new DataContext(connectionString)) {
    var objects = dc.ExecuteQuery<YourType>(sql); // now iterate object
}
```

Additionally, the sql can be automatically parameterized using `string.Format` rules:

```
class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
using(var dc = new DataContext(connectionString)) {
    List<Person> people = dc.ExecuteQuery(@"
          SELECT Id, Name Address
          FROM [People]
          WHERE [Name] = {0}", name).ToList(); // some LINQ too

}
```

Of course, you can also use the VS tools to create a typed data-context, allowing things like:

```
using(var dc = new SpecificDataContext(connectionString)) {
    List<Person> people =
         (from person in dc.People
          where person.Name == name
          select person).ToList();
}
```

Comment: All the comments disappeared and apparently I marked this as the correct answer, what happened here?

Answer (score 8):

You could use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to do this. [ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29) (checkout the [video tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos)) and [NHibernate](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14068) are popular choices.

Comment: LINQ to Entities is intended to replace both ADO.NET Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx