# Read object from c# database into classes directly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, serialization

What I am trying to do is read a database, row by row, and use the data from each row to initialize an object of the type that data represents. In this case I am reading rows of the Device table and trying to create Device objects with that data. I saw this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120175/deserialize-a-database-table-row-straight-into-a-c-sharp-object-is-there-a-mec):

and I tried this snippet:

```
     using(var dc = new DataContext(connectionString)) 
     {
              List<Person> people = dc.ExecuteQuery(@"
              SELECT Id, Name Address
              FROM [People]
              WHERE [Name] = {0}", name).ToList(); // some LINQ too
     }
```

But it is telling me

> The type arguments for this usage cannot be inferred from the usage

Is this in principal correct or should I be using the BondIO serializer/deserializer? as mentioned [here](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html)

Also the order of the members in the object may not be the same as the order of the columns in the database, is this relevant?

Later that same day....

I now have a DBContext with all my database objects defined like this:

```
    public class MyContext : DBContext
    {
            public dbSet<Device>{ get; set;}
            etc...
    }
```

And I now try to get object using this snippet:

```
    using (var db = new MyContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            var res = db.Device.Find(ID);
        }
```

However this gives an exception message

> Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention`2

I have checked the database and it should return 1 value based on the PrimaryKey ID that I am passing. Anybody have any hints what I'm still doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because ExecuteQuery is for executing statements, not for querying database. You should use **SqlQuery** instead
What you can do is, to create a new class with the properties you want to set in your query, means a simplified version of your query. In your case

```
public class Device
{
  public int  Id {get;set} 
  public string  Name {get;set} 
  public string  Address {get;set}
}
```

then use it as

```
var people = dc.ExecuteQuery<Device>(@"
              SELECT Id, Name Address
              FROM [People]
              WHERE [Name] = {0}", name).ToList();
```

Comment: But if I have the Device class already, with its members defined like you just have, why cant I query all columns and load them straight into the Device object?

Comment: I am soory - My answer is wrong. I am correcting it.

Comment: Do you mean ExecuteCommand?? DataContext.SqlQuery doesnt seem to exist....

Comment: I am sorry - I think I am totally mistaken. I was actually referring to DBContext of the Entity Framework. With DataContext it should be ExecuteQuery

Comment: There is definitely a easy solution to do this, I have seen it in a previous project I worked on, but I just cannot remember right now...Will answer this question when I find it